If $f^{\prime}(x)<x \;$ $\forall x\in \mathbb R$ and $f(0)=1$, then $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ can be (where $f(x)$ is differentiable function)
If $f^{\prime}(x)<x \;$ $\forall x\in \mathbb R$ and $f(0)=1$, then $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ can be (where $f(x)$ is differentiable function)
(A) $\dfrac{9}{8}$
(B) $\dfrac{3}{2}$
(C) $\dfrac{4}{3}$
(D) $\dfrac{5}{4}$
My Apporach:
Since $f'(x)<x$ and after Integrating both side I got $ f(x)<\dfrac{x^2}{2}+C$
Now Put $x=0$ Hence $f(0)<C\implies C>1$ and after putting $x=1$, I got $f(1)<\dfrac{1}{2}+C$
After applying by parts property of integration in  $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ I obtained $(xf(x))\bigg|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}xf'(x)dx\implies f(1)-\int_{0}^{1}xf'(x)dx$
and it is given that $f(x)<x$ hence I can say $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx>f(1)-\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx\implies \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx>f(1)-\dfrac{1}{3}$
Now I don't know how to solve it further.
Please anyone here can help me out?

HINT: try to use definite integrals instead of indefinite integrals. Since $C$ is any constant, you lose too much information. Recall that if $g$ is a positive function, then $\forall x$ you have $$\int_0^x g(t) dt >0$$

(following the previous comment) Another way of looking at it: for which constants $C$ is the inequality $f(x)<x^2/2+C$ true? What does this say about $f(1)$?

Use $f(x) = f(0)+ \int_0^x f'(t)dt$.

@copper.hat If I use $f(x)=x+\int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt$ then I obtain $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx<\dfrac{7}{6}$ which is more than $\dfrac{9}{8}$ So integral can be $\dfrac{9}{8}$. But Can we get exact figure of $\dfrac{9}{8}$?

What if $f'(x) = \alpha x$ for some $\alpha <1$.

Good job, the answer is 9/8.

@Crostul But can we obtain figure of $\dfrac{9}{8}$ instead of $\dfrac{7}{6}$?

@mathophile please read my previous comment.

If $f'(x)=\alpha x$ then $f(x)-f(0)=\alpha \cdot \dfrac{x^2}{2}\implies f(x)=\alpha \cdot \dfrac{x^2}{2}+1$ Hence $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\alpha \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}+1$ still I am getting $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx<\dfrac{7}{6}$

Since integrals preserve order we get
$$
f'(u) < u \implies \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} f'(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}x <  \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} u \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}x \tag{1}
$$
The right hand side of $(1)$ becomes
$$
 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} u \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}x =  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{2}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac16
$$
And the left hand side of $(1)$ is
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} f'(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}x \overset{\color{blue}{\text{FTC}}}{=} \int_{0}^{1}f(x) - \underbrace{f(0)}_{\color{purple}{1}} \,  \mathrm{d}x  =  \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,  \mathrm{d}x - 1
$$
Combining it all we get
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,  \mathrm{d}x  \mathbin{\color{red}{<}} \frac16 +1 = \color{red}{\frac76} \tag{2}
$$
If you now line up all the possible answers in increasing order (and also including $7/6$) we see that
$$
\frac{9}{8}  \mathbin{\color{red}{<}}\color{red}{\frac76}  < \frac54 < \frac43< \frac32
$$
And because of $(2)$ we get that $\boxed{\frac{9}{8}}$ is the only possible answer.

You actually can't say more about the specific value of $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. Pick any constant $\xi \in \left(-\infty, \frac76\right)$. We define the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
g(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} +\left(2 \xi - \frac{7}{3}\right)x +1  
$$
Notice now the following:
$\require{cancel}$

$g(0) = 1$.
$g'(x) = x + 2\xi - \frac{7}{3}$. Since $\xi < \frac76$ then multiplying by $2$ gives $2\xi < \frac73$ or $\color{blue}{2\xi -\frac73 < 0}$. Thus $$ g'(x) = x + 2\xi - \frac{7}{3} \mathbin{\color{blue}{<}} x +0 = x$$
which holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
We have $$\int_0^1 g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{2} +\left(2 \xi - \frac{7}{3}\right)x +1  \, \mathrm{d}x = \cancel{\frac16}  +  \xi - \cancel{\frac{7}{6}} +\cancel{1}  = \xi$$
We have shown that $g$ is an example that satisfies the hypothesis whose integral $\int_{0}^{1} g(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$ can be any value less than $\frac{7}{6}$ that you want.

